# Change Navigation Active when Scrolling

Tags: jquery, html, css, scroll

I want the navigation links to have an "Active" class and to change when scrolling.  The code I have only worked when the user clicks on the links.  If the user is scrolling manually through the page, then the active class does not change.  Any suggestions?

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on("scroll", onScroll);

    //smoothscroll
    $('a[href^="#"]').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(document).off("scroll");

        $('a').each(function () {
            $(this).removeClass('active');
        })
        $(this).addClass('active');

        var target = this.hash,
            menu = target;
        $target = $(target);
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            'scrollTop': $target.offset().top+2
        }, 700, 'swing', function () {
            window.location.hash = target;
            $(document).on("scroll", onScroll);
        });
    });
});


    function onScroll(event){
    var scrollPos = $(document).scrollTop();
    $('nav a').each(function () {
        var currLink = $(this);
        var refElement = $(currLink.attr("href"));
        if (refElement.position().top <= scrollPos && refElement.position().top + refElement.height() > scrollPos) {
            $('nav ul li a').removeClass("active");
            currLink.addClass("active");
        }
        else{
            currLink.removeClass("active");
        }
    });
}



           <!-- navigation -->
  <nav>
   <ul>
     <li><a href="#bmi">text</a></li>
     <li><a href="#health">text</a></li>
     <li><a href="#home" class="active">text</a></li>
   </ul>
  </nav>
</header>


<section id="home">
</section>

<section id="health">
</section> 

<section id="bmi">
</section>
```

Comment: can you share your html?

Comment: I added nav and sections html

Answer (score 0):

I have used this function for the same. Try this

```
var selector = 'nav a';
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        onScrollt(selector);
    });
    function onScrollt(selector) {
        var scrollPos = $(document).scrollTop();
        $(selector).each(function() {
            var currLink = $(this);
            var refElement = $(currLink.attr("href"));
            if (parseInt(refElement.position().top) <= scrollPos && parseInt(refElement.position().top) + parseInt(refElement.height()) > scrollPos) {
                $(selector).removeClass("active");
                currLink.addClass("active");
            } else {
                currLink.removeClass("active");
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

i have created a sample here, try this, may be this will help you

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on("scroll", onScroll);
    
    //smoothscroll
    $('a[href^="#"]').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(document).off("scroll");
        
        $('a').each(function () {
            $(this).removeClass('active');
        })
        $(this).addClass('active');
      
        var target = this.hash,
            menu = target;
        $target = $(target);
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            'scrollTop': $target.offset().top+2
        }, 500, 'swing', function () {
            window.location.hash = target;
            $(document).on("scroll", onScroll);
        });
    });
});

function onScroll(event){
    var scrollPos = $(document).scrollTop();
    $('#menu-center a').each(function () {
        var currLink = $(this);
        var refElement = $(currLink.attr("href"));
        if (refElement.position().top <= scrollPos && refElement.position().top + refElement.height() > scrollPos) {
            $('#menu-center ul li a').removeClass("active");
            currLink.addClass("active");
        }
        else{
            currLink.removeClass("active");
        }
    });
}
```

```css
body, html {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
.menu {
    width: 100%;
    height: 75px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
    position: fixed;
    background-color:rgba(4, 180, 49, 0.6);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
.light-menu {
    width: 100%;
    height: 75px;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
    position: fixed;
    background-color:rgba(4, 180, 49, 0.6);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
#menu-center {
    width: 980px;
    height: 75px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#menu-center ul {
    margin: 15px 0 0 0;
}
#menu-center ul li {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0 30px 0 0;
    display: inline;
}
.active {
    font-family:'Droid Sans', serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height: 50px;
}
a {
    font-family:'Droid Sans', serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height: 50px;
}
#home {
    background-color: grey;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-image: url(images/home-bg2.png);
}
#portfolio {
    background-image: url(images/portfolio-bg.png);
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
#about {
    background-color: blue;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
#contact {
    background-color: red;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="m1 menu">
    <div id="menu-center">
        <ul>
            <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#about">About</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a>

            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="home"></div>
<div id="portfolio"></div>
<div id="about"></div>
<div id="contact"></div>
```

Comment: I tried using your JS code, but I still cant get it to change upon scrolling.  IT only changes when I click one of the navigation links.  This should have nothing to do with the CSS right?

Answer (score 0):

**Below code works on scroll and on click. I have used your code to depict the scenario.**

> Below is the working example ..

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on("scroll", onScroll);

  //smoothscroll
  $('a[href^="#"]').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(document).off("scroll");

    $('a').each(function() {
      $(this).removeClass('active');
    })
    $(this).addClass('active');

    var target = this.hash,
      menu = target;
    $target = $(target);
    $('html, body').stop().animate({
      'scrollTop': $target.offset().top + 2
    }, 500, 'swing', function() {
      window.location.hash = target;
      $(document).on("scroll", onScroll);
    });
  });
});

function onScroll(event) {
  var scrollPos = $(document).scrollTop();
  $('nav a').each(function() {
    var currLink = $(this);
    var refElement = $(currLink.attr("href"));
    if (refElement.position().top <= scrollPos && refElement.position().top + refElement.height() > scrollPos) {
      $('nav ul li a').removeClass("active");
      currLink.addClass("active");
    } else {
      currLink.removeClass("active");
    }
  });
}
```

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%:
}

* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-boz;
}

section {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

nav ul {
  width: 100%;
  background: yellow;
  position: fixed;
}

nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px 0;
  margin-left: 20px;
  list-style: none;
}

nav ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

nav ul li a.active {
  color: white
}

section {
  background: red;
}

section+section {
  background: green;
}

section+section+section {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#bmi">text</a></li>
      <li><a href="#health">text</a></li>
      <li><a href="#home" class="active">text</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>


<section id="home">
</section>

<section id="health">
</section>

<section id="bmi">
</section>
```